# How to Split <ul>'s every 6 <li>'s

Tags: html, ejs

for example i have here my code, i want to add `<ul>` every 6 li's

I tried inserting ul inside the if statement but it wont work. is it possible to put ul without putting it outside the if?

```html
<%  if(array4[j].input_type == "radio") { %>

<li class="list-group-item radio-choice" id="chk_<%=array4[j].variable_name%>" value=""><%=array4[j].answer_text%> </li>

<%}%>
```

Comment: You can use mod. %

Comment: What do you mean by mod %?

Comment: @JohnCarloVelasquez What language are you using? `<%` and `%>` are not Javascript or HTML. I'm guessing PHP.

Comment: Are your LI's being produced within a loop?

Comment: Im using Node.JS , and yes it is produced by a loop

Comment: What reason do you have for splitting the items into separate lists? You may be able to use CSS to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
<% 
for(var j = 0, k = 0; j < array4.length; j++) {
  if(array4[j].input_type == "radio") {
%>

<li class="list-group-item radio-choice" id="chk_<%=array4[j].variable_name%>" value=""><%=array4[j].answer_text%> </li>

<% 
    if(k > 0 && !(k%6) && array4.length-1 != j) { 
%>
</ul>
<ul>
<%
    } 
    k++; 
  }
}
%>
</ul>
```

For something easier to read with comments:

```
// start <ul>
for(var j = 0, k = 0; j < array4.length; j++) {
  if(array4[j].input_type == "radio") {

    // add <li> here

    // if we're not at the beginning of the array
    // and we're on a multiple of 6
    // and we're not at the end of the array
    if(k > 0 && !(k%6) && array4.length-1 != j) { 

      // close one <ul> and open another

    }
    k++;
  }
}
// end <ul>
```

The [remainder operator (`%`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) (also known as the modulus operator) makes this easier.

Comment: @JohnCarloVelasquez Yeah, I originally thought you were using PHP. I've updated it for node.js.

Comment: sir can i ask if it is possible to have an if statement if the condition is to sort all same variables, for example i have name=[a,a,a,a,a,x,x,y,y,z,z,z]

Comment: @JohnCarloVelasquez Cool, glad I could help. Feel free to upvote any answers you find useful. Also feel free to mark an answer as accepted if it best meets your needs.

Comment: @JohnCarloVelasquez That sounds like a separate question. Feel free to post another question so that this can be addressed on its own.